# DrawerLayoutAndroid in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying 'DrawerLayoutAndroid' in react native with inside the drawer I added the react-navigation  'stackNavigator' to navigate between screen.[What I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOGLX.jpg)

but the problem is when I navigate it opens in the drawer
How do I open it full screen as a normal page
Is there a better method to achieve this
(redux state ?)
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution
what I did is created a routing page and added it as the root component

routes.js

```
    import Main from '../screens/main';
    import Ad from '../screens/adView';
    export const AdNav = StackNavigator({
      Home:{screen:Main,
      navigationOptions:{
        header:null,
       }  
    },
      Ad:{screen:Ad,
      navigationOptions:{
        title:'Details',      
    }}
    }

    );
```

App.js

```
import {AdNav} from './src/config/routes';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  render() {
   return (
   <View style={styles.container}> 
       <AdNav />
   </View>
   );
  }
}
```

Then I added DrawerLayoutAndroid to the main screen
inside the drawer layout I used stackNavigator to navigate with no issues

main screen with DrawerLayoutAndroid

```
render() {
var navigationView = (
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
<Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Ad')} title="go to next page"/>
</View>
 );
return (
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
      drawerWidth={300}
      drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
      renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
<View style={styles.container}>
{/*content*/}
</View>        
    </DrawerLayoutAndroid>

);
}
}
```